# std::vector of movable-only lambdas, is it possible?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move-semantics

I'd like to have a collection of lambdas, with the requirement that the lambas must not be copied, only moved.
This is because the lambas may need to move-capture some of their arguments that are not copy-constructible.

Example:

```
NonCopyableType varName ;
auto func = [a=move(varName)](){ ... } ; //varName is move-captured
```

After this I want to store `func` in a `vector`, but I can't use the `std::function` type because it requires the lambdas to be copyable.

```
vector<function<void()>> list ;
list.push_back(func) ; //won't work
```

Is it possible to do this some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Just write your own `function` clone that is move-only. Here's a simplified version that only supports nullary callables, but you can see how it can be extended:

```
class move_function
{
    struct placeholder {
        virtual ~placeholder() = default;
        virtual void call() = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct holder : placeholder {
        T f;
        void call() override { f(); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<placeholder> f_;

public:
    template <class F,
        class R = std::result_of_t<F&()>,
        std::enable_if_t<!std::convertible<std::decay_t<F>*, move_function*>::value, int> = 0>
    move_function(F&& f)
        : f_(new std::decay_t<F>{std::forward<F>(f)})
    { }

    void operator()() const { f_->call(); }
};
```

All the implicitly defined special member functions already do the right thing for us.

Comment: See also [P0288](http://wg21.link/p0288) and the [cxx_function library](https://github.com/potswa/cxx_function).

Comment: This makes me wonder, why is it that `std::function` requieres copyability in the first place. STL containers don't requiere it and they play quite well with the rest of the library.

Comment: @GetFree The principle of type erasure requires that the type provides every capability that `function` does. The default constructor of `set<T>` doesn't need to access the copy constructor of `T`. But when you convert `T` to `function<ret()>`, all the relevant functionality of `T` needs to be captured immediately because `function` has no means to remember `T` afterwards.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, so in simpler words, containers require only what you use. If you don't copy a container, it doesn't need to be copyable. Whereas `std:function` requieres every capability whether you use it or not.